# How to make a wordpress theme compatible with Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I wrote a [WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/) theme, I want to let it compatible with [Elementor](https://developers.elementor.com/), where can I start my work?

Answer (score 2):

There are few things to consider before making a theme compatible with Elementor:

First you need to register location in functions.php
Locations are organized in groups:Header, Footer, Single, Archive.
To register all location:

```
function theme_prefix_register_elementor_locations( $elementor_theme_manager ) {

     $elementor_theme_manager->register_all_core_location();

}
add_action( 'elementor/theme/register_locations', 'theme_prefix_register_elementor_locations' );
```

Second, Display locations in the Theme: We use `elementor_theme_do_location()`
Example, displaying Archive location:

```
<?php
get_header();

// Elementor `archive` location
if ( ! function_exists( 'elementor_theme_do_location' ) || ! elementor_theme_do_location( 'archive' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/archive' );
}

get_footer();
```

Then, make sure to remove container if using elemntor template:

```
<?php  
      if( !is_page_template('elementor_header_footer')) ){ ?>
         <div class="container">
    <?php 
    } ?>
```

Remember always to use conditionnal tags to test in case elementor is not installed, otherwise it will throw errors.
More detail: [Elementor Theme location API](https://developers.elementor.com/theme-locations-api/)

Answer (score 0):

To make your theme compatible with the Elementor page builder plugin, you need to take care of few things.

- We normally use container class after main content. If the page/post is using the Elementor template, you need to remove the container class
- Most of the theme designers use padding on the content of the theme. You can remove content padding if the page is an Elementor template.
- It is very important to make styles of your main theme easily overridable by styles of Elementor. So, Do not use !important